# How To Stop Animation

Tags: wpf

I Have Button In My Project , When Click On It Began To Rotate Forever And Some Task Is Executed

But I Want When Work Of This Task Finish My Animation Stop

Do you have a suggestion ?

(My Animation Defined By xaml)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [Fill Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.fillbehavior.aspx) enumeration to Stop, use the [BeingAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx) method specifying the property you are using and passing null for the animation timeline, or set the entire storyboard to null. [Another example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx#fillbehaviorsection)